# Apache does not show and does not follow SymLinks

Tags: apache-2.2, symbolic-link

On Linux Fedora 15, Apache doesn't follow symlinks, and they did not show in directory index... Can you help me why?

Just to mention that in httpd.conf I do have :

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Also, User and Group defined in httpd.conf are owners of proper directories where is web application saved...

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance!!!

**UPDATE:** is a problem occured because target is on the other hard drive?

**UPDATE 2:** it follows symbolic links, but this link for some reason is not followed. It points to the dir on other hard drive.

**UPDATE 3:** there is "nothing special" after first direction, ie:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I think the FollowSymlinks should be in your webroot-dir, possibly `/var/www`.

Comment: What's the rest of your config look like?  Just because you've set `FollowSymLinks` on the root, doesn't mean it's not unset somewhere else..

Comment: no, nothing special after first Follow... pls check updated part of my message...

Comment: `AllowOverride All` makes it possible for `FollowSymLinks` to be turned off in a `.htaccess`-file.

Comment: tnx for advice, but, no, it's not turned off with htaccess :-((((

Comment: it looks like i can not browse directories outside webroot-dir

Comment: Is it something to do with SeLinux?!

Comment: Yes, it is because of **SeLinux**.

Next line helped me:

    chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /myDir/*


Thank you all!

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer and accept when avaiable.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that Apache has read permission in the directory the link points too. Giving read permission on the link itself is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm very late for this question, but maybe I can help someone else. I had the same problem and finally I solved it: you have to change permissions of all parent directories of the target of your symbolic link. In my case -e.g.- the link pointed to /run/media/username/device/subdirectory/target (I use arch linux). So I needed to change "username" and "subdirectory" access permissions (the other ones should be fine by default):

```
setfacl -m "u:http:r-x" /run/media/username/device/subdirectory
setfacl -m "u:http:r-x" /run/media/username
```

For the latter you need root permissions
(and, of course, http is httpd user defined in httpd.conf).

Comment: If you are a developer working on source code in your home folder  "/home/user" is the one www--data needs access to.  This caught me out for ages. (Thanks for the light bulb moment).

Answer (score 0):

If only this link is a problem, it makes me think the link is the problem and not the Apache config. Are you sure it is not broken or the target drive is not mounted properly? For a file on a seperate drive `ls -l` should show, for example:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group size date time link_name -> /drive/mount/point/path/to/file/file_name
```

If it does not then you should remake the link using:

```
rm link_name
ln -s /drive/mount/point/path/to/file/file_name link_name
```

If the link is pointing to the right place, perhaps the target drive is not mounted. Remount it and try again. Best of luck!